# understanding this function prototype

Tags: c++, reference, signature

In my CS class we are learning about how structs are not considered OOP and in our program we have to use a node `class` instead of `struct` now. In `class node` there is a function

```
node *& go_left();
```

What does the `*&` in the declaration mean? The class is also called `node`, so does that mean it's returning a pointer to another `node` object?

Comment: "*structs are not considered OOP*" - that is not true.  In C++, `struct` and `class` are *identical* in all regards, except one - the default member visibility is `public` for `struct` and `private` for `class`. You can use `struct` for OOP

Comment: A nitpick, just to annoy people: despite the fact that C++ recognizes "function prototype scope", there's no normative concept of "prototype" in C++. The term exists in C, where you have prototype and non-prototype function declarations. In C++ there's no such distinction. The above is just a function *declaration*. (I'll show myself out now.)

Answer (score 1):

The "node" is a class and therefore becomes a user defined data type. 
As far as the Node *& is concerned, your method returns a pointer of the type "node", by reference